# While-loop will not terminate in console after entering numbers

Tags: java

I keep trying to get this to work but when I enter in the numbers and enter them into the console it does not finish. I have to terminate myself.

```
import java.util.Scanner;


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int cmlSum = 0;
        int inputNum;
        String outputSum = "";
    
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter sequence of numbers ");
    
        do {
            inputNum = keyboard.nextInt();
            cmlSum += inputNum;
            outputSum += String.format("%s ", String.valueOf(cmlSum));
        } while (keyboard.hasNextInt());
    
        System.out.println(outputSum);
    }
```

Comment: use `break` to terminate the loop.

Comment: When would you expect `hasNextInt()` to return *false* when entering input from the console?

Answer (score 0):

Well, yes.  The `keyboard.hasNextInt()` call will return `false` for two reasons.

- The next token is a NOT an integer.
- You have reached the end-of-input.

What is (most likely) happening is that you have stopped entering numbers.  The program is (patiently) waiting for you to enter ... something.

Solutions:

1. Tell the user to enter the (OS specific) terminal "end of file" character.  On Linux it is CTRL-D.  On Windows CTRL-Z.
2. Tell the user to enter something that isn't an integer.
3. Pick an integer as meaning that there are no more numbers, and test for that.

You also need to instruct the user how to "end" the sequence; e.g.

```
  System.out.println("Enter sequence of numbers.  Enter a non-number to stop.");
```

This is actually a problem with your application's "user interface" design.  If the user is expected to type an arbitrarily long sequence of numbers (or something else), then there needs to be some way for the user to **tell** the program that the sequence is finished.  The program cannot magically distinguish the cases of "there are no more" and "hang on, I'm taking a break from typing".

Comment: So the only way to actually end it is if the user terminates the command

Comment: No.  There are TWO other alternatives.  See "Solutions".

Comment: Or you could use a special number (e.g. -1) to mean "no more".

Answer (score 0):

The `hasNext()` method checks if the Scanner has another token in its `input`. A Scanner `breaks` its input into tokens using a delimiter pattern, which matches `whitespace` by default. That is, `hasNext()` checks the input and `returns true` if it has another `non-whitespace` character.

In this case `hasNext()` won't `return` `true` because there is neither any `integer` nor any `whitespace`. Therefore the program waits for the next input. Besides use a specific integer to `break` the `loop`.

for instance,

```
System.out.println("Input -1 will end the program!";
do{
    int x = keyboard.nextInt();
    if(x == -1){
        break;
    }
    //do something
}while(true);
```

Comment: Where did you determine that a -1 indicates the end of data from?

Comment: @ScottHunter This is an example . Moreover, as mentioned already _"use a specific integer to break the loop"_;

Answer (score 0):

Your code is `ok`. There is no issue.

But before writing code, we need to think about it. The workflow of your code below:

1. 1st time when we enter `do` loop, `keyboard.nextInt()` takes input from us.
2. Then it calculates the `sum` and performs `string` operation.
3. After that, `while`'s `keyboard.hasNextInt()` takes next input from you.

   - Checks your input. If your input is `not an integer`, `while` loop will terminate(break).
   - If your input is an integer then, code loop back to `keyboard.nextInt()`. But this time, it does not take input from you.
   - It pases the buffered input(keyboard.hasNextInt()) to `keyboard.nextInt()` and assign the value to `inputNum`

So, when you want to terminate while loop, you should input any `character` like a, b, c, etc.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't specified when the loop will end. Have a condition such as inputting a certain number that will end the program once entered, as currently your program is just going to wait for more input. Something like :

```
System.out.println("Enter sequence of numbers to add. Enter '0' to end the program");

do {
   inputNum = keyboard.nextInt();
   cmlSum += inputNum;
   outputSum += String.format("%s ", String.valueOf(cmlSum));
} while (inputNum != 0);//Keeps going as long as 0 is not entered
    
//When zero is entered, program shows the total sum and terminates
if (inputNum == 0) {
   System.out.println("The sum of all total numbers: ");
   System.out.println(outputSum);
   System.exit(0);//Terminates program
}
```

Answer (score -2):

**Basic syntax of do-while Loop:**

```
do{

   // do something

}while(terminating condition);
```

If you are using **hasNextInt()** method of Scanner object for **terminating condition** in do-while loop **then loop will be terminated once it get input other than an integer value** (e.g float, double, char, String etc.. ) as shown in below complete program.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Cumulative{

    public static void main(String[] args){

        int cmlSum = 0;
        int inputNum;
        String outputSum = "";
        
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter sequence of numbers ");
        
        do{
            inputNum = keyboard.nextInt();
            cmlSum += inputNum;
            outputSum += String.format("%s ", String.valueOf(cmlSum));
        }while (keyboard.hasNextInt()); // loop will terminated whenever get any value other than valid integer such  as float char or String etc..
        
        System.out.println(outputSum);
    }
}
```

Comment: And this is different from the posted code how?

Comment: You are explaining something that the OP apparently already understands, without addressing the problem that she or he doesn't understand.